# How to include category id in url on category list page?

Tags: magento-2.1, category, url-rewrite, magento-2.1.3, category-listing

i want to include category id included in url on category list page.
My default category url is listed below::

http://magento2.shelltag.com/women/bags/backpacks

I want to show it like this :

http://magento2.shelltag.com/women/bags/backpacks-6

I want URLs for different categories when a user opens a Category page

[magento2.shelltag.com/women/bags/backpacks-6](http://magento2.shelltag.com/women/bags/backpacks-6)
[magento2.shelltag.com/women/bags-8](http://magento2.shelltag.com/women/bags-8) 
[magento2.shelltag.com/women-10](http://magento2.shelltag.com/women-10)

How can it be achieved?

[image]

Comment: any suggestions please?

Comment: do i have to use observer in this?

Comment: how to achieve this functionality?

Comment: You can directly add category id to your category url from admin panel category management.

Comment: but cant i achieve this functionality via programming...i have more than 150 categories....i have managed to do it for product list pages via programming but i applied same thing on category and it didn't worked out.so i want to achieve this via programming?

Comment: Can you add what you tried to achieve this for categories?

Comment: i have created a new plugin and used the inherited class
ProductProcessUrlRewriteSavingObserver.php
class ModifyProductUrlKeyPlugin
{
     public function beforeExecute(
  \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Observer\ProductProcessUrlRewriteSavingObserver $subject,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $id = $product->getId();
        $urlKey = $product->getUrlKey();

        if (rtrim($urlKey, $id) == $urlKey) {
            $product->setUrlKey($id . '_' . $urlKey); 
        }
    }
}

Comment: i manage to achieve below url on product list page
http://shelltagserver.shelltag.com/index.php/2045-erika-running-short.html

2045 is product id that is showing in url..same i want to do for category on category list page

Comment: and its related to magento2.1.3

Comment: sir why you have deleted the answer?

Comment: Yes, because it won't be applicable for your requirements. I'll add another if I could find solution.

Comment: have you got its solution sir?
like if iam on particular category id will show for that category only not others

Comment: Sorry Yogesh, but I have not got any solution for your issue yet.

Comment: ok fine sir i will wait